# Finding air-travel time between airports

Tags: air-travel, airports

I'm looking to write a program that will let me create a query of two US airports and return the flight time between them (probably an average flight time for A->B, since I recognise there can be slight variations in the times).

Is there some place I can get a list of flight times from A to B, so that I can query it directly or calculate the averages myself?

I also recognise that I could just calculate the distance "as the nazgul fly" and then divide it by some rate or whatnot, but this does not account for differences e.g. flying Eastbound v. flying Westbound.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  And while your question is interesting you are looking for data from private planes as well as airlines.  This would be a question off topic as far as [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) is concerned.

Comment: Agree this is off-topic. You would get great answers to this on http://stackoverflow.com/ (sister site of this)

Answer (score 3):

You can get data from http://flightaware.com about the time of recent commercial flights between two airports.  For example, [here](http://flightaware.com/live/findflight/KDEN/KSTL/) is a list of flights from Denver to St. Louis.  Each is shown with its *scheduled* arrival and departure times, but if you click on an individual flight, you can see the actual takeoff and landing times.

For airport pairs that don't currently have commercial nonstop service, I don't think you can do much except estimate based on distance.